# Ghost/translucent caption inside text input?

Tags: apache-flex

First, what does one call the ghost caption that appears in a text edit if that edit has no real text?

Second, has anyone invented that particular wheel for Flex text components?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a Watermark.

I'm not an expert on Flex but here is one example:

http://labs.flexperiments.nl/writing-components-in-flex-part-2/